# Cloudinary upload image with HTTPS url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary

I am using a Rails app to upload images (or files) to cloudinary. I am using Carrierwave as uploader. Everything works fine locally, but I see that images are uploaded with http://something.

This does not work in production, since my domain is HTTPS, therefore, when I ask for a HTTP, it fails, since I need HTTPS.

Any help? I checked the documentation and they say that they work with HTTPS, that's why I am confused. I also wrote them, but it would be nice if someone had the same issue and knows how to solve it.

Comment: I still use it in production. Check this answer in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319992/ruby-on-rails-is-saving-images-through-form-in-app-assets-images-possible/49320525#49320525

Answer (score -1):

The upload response includes "secure_url", or you can just use "https://res.cloudinary.com..."

--Yakir