# Can I run two uploaders in a Ruby On Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, cloudinary, uploader, shrine

I have a Ruby On Rails app (Ruby 2.3.8 Rails 4.2.7.1) running Shrine as an image and document uploader.  I want to do an integration with the image manipulation company Cloudinary which uses Carrierwave as an uploader. Do I need to re-write the whole code to run Carrierwave or can I run two uploaders (doing different tasks) in the same stack?

Comment: No, just need a new uploader class for specific task. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319992/ruby-on-rails-is-saving-images-through-form-in-app-assets-images-possible/49320525#49320525

Comment: You can use shrine with Cloudinary: https://github.com/shrinerb/shrine-cloudinary. If that helps.